# Inserting a document with PyMongo passed through Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am trying to pass data via an http request through the flask python framework and insert it into mongodb with the help of pymongo.

My code is as such:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import json_util
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

#setting up the flask app
app=Flask(__name__)

#connecting to mongoDB
client=MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client["test"] #db name
col=db["test"] #collection name

@app.route('/data/insert/', methods=['GET'])
def insert():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        result = request.data('docs')
        col.insert(result)
    return "it worked!\n"

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

I am passing data through the url:

```
127.0.0.1:5000/data/insert/docs={"hello":"world"}
```

the weird thing is that it's accepting the data and even spitting it back out when I try to simply return it in string format, but it needs to be converted or accessed in a way that I'm missing.

Ps. I already tried the proper escaped characters for the brackets and double-quotes.

Comment: When asking a question, please make sure to include a description of the problem. Right now, you have just said that you're "having a problem", but not saying what the problem is. Are you getting an error? If so, show the full stack trace. Is the data not being inserted the way you expect? If so, how did you expect it to be inserted? What did you do to test that the data was not inserted correctly? Did you test that the data coming from Flask (`result`) was the correct type that was expected by PyMongo?

Comment: Essentially it would cause Flask to return an error 404 page that I assume is flask's default. I did eventually solve the problem by implementing something similar to dm03514's answer posted below. I will keep your advice in mind when asking in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that `result = request.data('docs')` is returning a string,

I believe [`insert`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert) requires a dictionary, not a string

Perhaps, somethign like:

`result = json.loads(request.data('docs'))`

The above uses python's built in `json` library to try and parse the `docs` string into python datatypes.  Remember to handle the case if `docs` is invalid JSON!